# Does the title of Kaagaz Ke Phool carry any significance?

Tags: title, kaagaz-ke-phool

What is the significance (if any) of the title of [Kaagaz Ke Phool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaagaz_Ke_Phool)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[As discussed on IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0052954/reviews):

An interpretation of the title Kaagaz ke phool (exact translation means "Paper flowers".) Bees look for honey and hunt for flowers. A song from movie "Dekhi zamaane ki yaari" says "Oh thirsty bees, fly away from here these are all Paper flowers (naturally they don't have what the bees are searching for!").
So this name suits the movie in a way that it's saying the world as artificial paper flowers.